# what is the role of Update( ) in VTK?

Tags: vtk

I m a new in vtk and i want to know what is the role of Update here , we can just use vtkNew sphereSource; and its will work

```
vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource;
  sphereSource->Update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks the algorithm to do the actual computation (see the [doc](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAlgorithm.html#afa4eff301069b8b47703cd4939aeffa7)). It is because VTK is lazy evaluated, so output is computed only when required. It allows you to change algorithm parameters without triggering unneeded computations.

Example:

```cpp
vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource;
sphereSource->Update(); // compute sphere with default
vtkPolyData* sphere = sphereSource->GetOutput();
sphereSource->SetThetaResolution(100); // change from default. Does not trigger any computation.
vtkPolyData* oldSphere = sphereSource->GetOutput(); // old output, source still not recomputed
sphereSource->Update(); // compute new sphere
vtkPolyData* sphere100 = sphereSource->GetOutput(); // new output
```